# Mongoose with match conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a query in mongoose that looks up and populates orders for a 'specific' user, but I can't seem to get the arguments to work on the match.

Even though I do pass the match param through as per the mongoose documents, I still get all orders for all users returned.

Here is my code:

```
async getUserOrderList(params) {
    let pUser = params.callParams.profileUser;

    try {
        let dbFilter = { _active: true };
        let dbFields = { _id: 1, company: 1, jobs: 1, reference: 1, placedDate: 1, paymentStatus: 1, total: 1 };

        let resultsData = await Orders.find(dbFilter, dbFields, handlePagination())
            .populate({
                path: "company",
                match: { "company.user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pUser) },
                select: ["_id", "name", "user"],
                populate: [
                    {
                        path: "user",
                        select: ["_id", "firstName", "lastName", "consultant"],
                        populate: [
                            {
                                path: "consultant",
                                select: ["firstName", "lastName"],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            })
            .populate({
                path: "jobs",
                select: ["service"],
                populate: [
                    {
                        path: "service",
                        select: ["name"],
                    },
                ],
            });

        let resultsCount = await Orders.countDocuments(dbFilter).populate({
            path: "company",
            match: { "company.user": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(pUser) },
        });

        return { d: resultsData, c: resultsCount };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I missing and should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 1):

You're not matching active orders that have a `company.user` matching `pUser`, you're matching all active orders and only populating the `company` field for each order where `company.user` matches the user.

See [this documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) (emphasis mine):

> **The `match` option doesn't filter out `Story` documents**. If there are no documents that satisfy match, you'll get a `Story` document with an empty `fans` array.

So you need to apply a match on the `Order` model if you want to limit the results to matching a specific company.

However, with population, you also can't use this:

```
let dbFilter = { _active: true, 'company.user' : pUser };
```

That's because the `company` field in each order contains just an `ObjectId` (a reference to a `Company` document).

You have to perform this particular query in two steps:

- retrieve the company that matches the user:

  ```
  const company = await Company.findOne({ user : pUser });
  ```
- with that, filter the orders:

  ```
  let dbFilter = { _active : true, company : company._id };
  ```

**EDIT**

When a user can belong to multiple companies, find the list of companies first:

```
const companies = await Company.find({ user : pUser });
```

Then perform a query to find all orders belonging to one of the companies:

```
let dbFilter = {
  _active : true,
  company : { $in : companies.map(company => company._id) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does help a little, BUT a user can have more than one company and thus you would want to be able to look at all orders for all companies on that user. How would I go about that?

Comment: @Niishaw see edit.